# linkedin login for IOS and Android on React Native?

Tags: react-native, linkedin-api

how to implement linkedin login for IOS and Android on React Native? Please help.
I have already used "https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-linkedin-login". But this version is pretty old and it doesn't work.

Comment: what's the problem with this version? are you sure it doesn't work or you didn't configure it correctly?

Comment: @user2895560 Did you find a solution for adding linkedin login in react-native?